# ACCESS VBA date format change when changing numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small vba code to export from access to excel. I did a formatting for number data type in my code which changes my date format as well. I don't know the syntax for date format. Could some one help me please.

For your reference,

```
 For lvlcolumn = 0 To recsetnxair.Fields.Count - 1
     wrksheetnxair.Cells(1, lvlcolumn + 1).Value = _
                                recsetnxair.Fields(lvlcolumn).Name
     wrksheetnxair.Cells(1, lvlcolumn + 1).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = sFromat        
 Next lvlcolumn
```

This code works perfectly for numbers , now i need for the date as well.

Regards,
Jeeva

Comment: Have a look in the documentation for `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted using dbInteger or dbDouble respective field type with a user-defined format.

Regards,
Jeeva